# Assign value to a range with a variable column refreence

Tags: vba

The following code gives me a compile error:expected: separator or ).

```
   Public Sub test1()
        Dim first_column As String,a_tab as string
        a_tab="Sheet1"
        first_column = "A"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(a_tab).Range(first_column&"10").value="hello"
    End Sub
```

I know we can do it when the row reference is a variable, i.e.

```
Public Sub test1()
    dim fist_row as integer, a_tab as string
    a_tab="Sheet1"
    first_row=10
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(a_tab).Range("A"&first_row).value="hello"
End Sub
```

Could someone help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get out of the habit of using a letter for the column designation.

Your first column is column 1:
`Columns(1).Value = "Hello"` will place "Hello" in every cell in column 1 - `Range(A1:A1048576)`.

The second cell in column 1:
`Cells(2, 1) = "Hello"` will place "Hello" in row 2, column 1 - `Range(A2)`.

A range of cells designated by a start and end cell:
`Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(4, 2)) = "Hello"` will place "Hello" in every cell between row 2, column 1 and row 4, column 2 - `Range("A2:B4")`

The first, second, third & fourth columns:
`Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,4)).EntireColumn` - `Range("A:D")`.

But, saying that the only thing that caused your code to fail was spacing.  You'll notice with the row variable it keeps putting the spaces back in - doesn't seem to do that with the column variable:
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(a_tab).Range(first_column & "10").Value = "hello"`
- add a space either side of the ampersand.

**Edit:**
Consider placing values in columns CB:CL using a loop.  Using numbers you'd just write:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 80 To 90
        Cells(1, x) = "Hello"
    Next x

End Sub
```

Using letters you'd have to use something like:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim col_Letter As String

    col_Letter = "CB"

    Do
        Range(col_Letter & "10") = "Hello"
        'Get the next column letter by finding the address, splitting it and extracting just the column letter.
        col_Letter = Split(Range(col_Letter & "10").Offset(, 1).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
    Loop While col_Letter <> "CL"

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't believe it's spacing..I always thought VBA auto spaces everything such as =. I assumed it's the same thing with &. Thank you for the detailed response!

Comment: It's not always obvious.  I didn't notice until I tried your code and it highlighted the row.  Much simpler to use numbers rather than letters though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing spaces when concatenating strings in your argument to `Range`? `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(a_tab).Range(first_column & "10").value="hello"` Works for me if I add the spaces.